# Python interpretor skips my else block, throws error when I pass an integer

Tags: python, if-statement

The code with if-else statements:

```
def sqrtt(argument):
    if type(argument) == tuple or list or dict or set:
        result = [int(numpy.sqrt(i)) for i in argument]
    else:
        result = int(numpy.sqrt(argument))
    return result
```

The Response when I pass an integer as an argument:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anees\PycharmProjects\p5\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    l2 = sqrtt(1)
  File "C:\Users\anees\PycharmProjects\p5\main.py", line 33, in sqrtt
    result = [int(numpy.sqrt(i)) for i in argument]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to include your response and code as text, not image

Comment: Added code as requested, plz review it. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of making the function figure out if `argument` is a single value or an iterable, just require the caller to wrap a single value in the iterable container of their choice, and likewise return a possibly singleton container (which the caller can unpack).

Comment: @chepner Thanks mate, however I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean here when you say wrapping. Can you kindly show me how to do that with an example? Thanks.

Comment: Don't let the caller do something like `y = sqrtt(5)`. Make them create a list like `y, = sqrrt([5])`, and now your function can *assume* the argument is iterable instead of trying to detect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if type(argument) is `tuple`, and after that you are checking if `list`  or `dict` or `set` is True. If you would like to check if argument is one of those types you should do something like this:

```
def sqrtt(argument):
    if type(argument) == tuple or type(argument) == list or type(argument) == dict or type(argument) == set:
        result = [int(numpy.sqrt(i)) for i in argument]
    else:
        result = int(numpy.sqrt(argument))
    return result
```

Or you can check if argument is in iterable types

```
def sqrtt(argument):
    iterable_types = (tuple, list, dict, set)
    if type(argument) in iterable_types:
        result = [int(numpy.sqrt(i)) for i in argument]
    else:
        result = int(numpy.sqrt(argument))
    return result
```

Sadly, your code won't work for dict objects

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks mate. Just one quick question: Why won't it work for dict objects?

Comment: Don't compare to `type(argument)` at all, though. Use `isinstance(argument, (tuple, list, dict))` instead. (Or `isinstance(argument, collections.abc.Iterable)` for full generality).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wanted to keep answer in same "style" as OP code, but feel free to edit my answer if you think that would be better.